# How to compare data with data approximately one month before?

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have a table which contains data for consumption of electricity on different sites. The data is not regular in time. Which mean that sometimes let's say the data is for one site on a particular day and the next record for the same site would be for another day, not necessarily one month after. It is the column DATE_DE_DÉBUT_DE_PÉRIODE_DE_CONSOMMATION. I would like to compare with the record located the more near one month ago for the same site. Compare means finding the percentage of difference between the value in the column CONSOMMATION_TOTALE__KWH_.

For example if I have on record with :

| DATE_DE_DÉBUT_DE_PÉRIODE_DE_CONSOMMATION | CONSOMMATION_TOTALE__KWH_ |
| --- | --- |
| 01/02/2018 | 100 |
| 16/01/2018 | 80 |
| 02/01/2018 | 50 |

In this example the result would be :

| SITE | PERCENTAGE |
| --- | --- |
| ACHERES P7 VALENTON | 50 % |

We choose the year in a variable :YEAR for example ‘2018’ and the month with the number of the month, in this example ‘02’. Here is the table :

```sql
CREATE TABLE "FL_ENGIE_ELEC" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE  NOKEEP  NOSCALE  NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "DÉSIGNATION_SITE" VARCHAR2(255 BYTE), 
    "DATE_DE_DÉBUT_DE_PÉRIODE_DE_CONSOMMATION" DATE, 
    "DATE_DE_FIN_DE_PÉRIODE_DE_CONSOMMATION" DATE, 
    "CONSOMMATION_TOTALE__KWH_" NUMBER, 
     PRIMARY KEY ("ID"))
```

Some sample data:

```sql
(ID,"DÉSIGNATION_SITE","DATE_DE_DÉBUT_DE_PÉRIODE_DE_CONSOMMATION","DATE_DE_FIN_DE_PÉRIODE_DE_CONSOMMATION",CONSOMMATION_TOTALE__KWH_) values (1307,'BNE99782 STEU DU MOULIN DE GRANVILLE',to_date('25/01/2022 00:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI'),to_date('02/03/2022 00:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI'),26298);
Insert into FL_ENGIE_ELEC (ID,"DÉSIGNATION_SITE","DATE_DE_DÉBUT_DE_PÉRIODE_DE_CONSOMMATION","DATE_DE_FIN_DE_PÉRIODE_DE_CONSOMMATION",CONSOMMATION_TOTALE__KWH_) values (1308,'BNE99782 STEU DU MOULIN DE GRANVILLE',to_date('25/12/2021 00:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI'),to_date('24/01/2022 00:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI'),16855);
Insert into FL_ENGIE_ELEC (ID,"DÉSIGNATION_SITE","DATE_DE_DÉBUT_DE_PÉRIODE_DE_CONSOMMATION","DATE_DE_FIN_DE_PÉRIODE_DE_CONSOMMATION",CONSOMMATION_TOTALE__KWH_) values (1309,'BNE99782 STEU DU MOULIN DE GRANVILLE',to_date('03/03/2022 00:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI'),to_date('04/04/2022 00:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI'),30352);
Insert into FL_ENGIE_ELEC (ID,"DÉSIGNATION_SITE","DATE_DE_DÉBUT_DE_PÉRIODE_DE_CONSOMMATION","DATE_DE_FIN_DE_PÉRIODE_DE_CONSOMMATION",CONSOMMATION_TOTALE__KWH_) values (1310,'BNE99782 STEU DU MOULIN DE GRANVILLE',to_date('05/04/2022 00:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI'),to_date('03/05/2022 00:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI'), 2723);
Insert into FL_ENGIE_ELEC (ID,"DÉSIGNATION_SITE","DATE_DE_DÉBUT_DE_PÉRIODE_DE_CONSOMMATION","DATE_DE_FIN_DE_PÉRIODE_DE_CONSOMMATION",CONSOMMATION_TOTALE__KWH_) values (1311,'BNE99782 STEU DU MOULIN DE GRANVILLE',to_date('04/05/2022 00:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI'),to_date('24/05/2022 00:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI'),9878);
Insert into FL_ENGIE_ELEC (ID,"DÉSIGNATION_SITE","DATE_DE_DÉBUT_DE_PÉRIODE_DE_CONSOMMATION","DATE_DE_FIN_DE_PÉRIODE_DE_CONSOMMATION",CONSOMMATION_TOTALE__KWH_) values (1312,'BNE99782 STEU DU MOULIN DE GRANVILLE',to_date('25/05/2022 00:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI'),to_date('23/06/2022 00:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI'),13228);
Insert into FL_ENGIE_ELEC (ID,"DÉSIGNATION_SITE","DATE_DE_DÉBUT_DE_PÉRIODE_DE_CONSOMMATION","DATE_DE_FIN_DE_PÉRIODE_DE_CONSOMMATION",CONSOMMATION_TOTALE__KWH_) values (1313,'BNE99782 STEU DU MOULIN DE GRANVILLE',to_date('24/06/2022 00:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI'),to_date('24/07/2022 00:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI'),13385);
Insert into FL_ENGIE_ELEC (ID,"DÉSIGNATION_SITE","DATE_DE_DÉBUT_DE_PÉRIODE_DE_CONSOMMATION","DATE_DE_FIN_DE_PÉRIODE_DE_CONSOMMATION",CONSOMMATION_TOTALE__KWH_) values (1314,'BNE99782 STEU DU MOULIN DE GRANVILLE',to_date('25/07/2022 00:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI'),to_date('24/08/2022 00:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI'),22449);
```

I could not achieve to write the appropriate "select" statement.

```sql
with t as (
  2  select 1 site, date '2023-01-01' d, 20 kwh from dual union all
  3  select 1 site, date '2023-01-31' d, 21 kwh from dual union all
  4  select 1 site, date '2023-02-01' d, 23 kwh from dual union all
  5  select 1 site, date '2023-02-02' d, 24 kwh from dual union all
  6  select 1 site, date '2023-02-03' d, 25 kwh from dual union all
  7  select 1 site, date '2023-02-04' d, 26 kwh from dual union all
  8  select 1 site, date '2023-03-03' d, 27 kwh from dual union all
  9  select 2 site, date '2023-01-01' d, 12 kwh from dual union all
 10  select 2 site, date '2023-01-17' d, 15 kwh from dual union all
 11  select 2 site, date '2023-04-01' d, 22 kwh from dual union all
 12  select 2 site, date '2023-04-11' d, 17 kwh from dual)
 13  select  t.*
 14  ,last_value(kwh)
 15      over (partition by site
 16      order by d
 17      range between UNBOUNDED PRECEDING and interval '1' month preceding) lv2
 18  from t
 19* order by 1.2
```

In this example I don't get the percentage.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

```
with t as (
select 1 site, date '2023-01-01' d, 20 kwh 
from dual union all
select 1 site, date '2023-01-31' d, 21 kwh 
from dual union all  
select 1 site, date '2023-02-01' d, 23 kwh 
from dual union all  
select 1 site, date '2023-02-02' d, 24 kwh 
from dual union all  
select 1 site, date '2023-02-03' d, 25 kwh 
from dual union all 
select 1 site, date '2023-02-04' d, 26 kwh 
from dual union all 
select 1 site, date '2023-03-03' d, 27 kwh 
from dual union all 
select 2 site, date '2023-01-01' d, 12 kwh 
from dual union all 
select 2 site, date '2023-01-17' d, 15 kwh 
from dual union all 
select 2 site, date '2023-04-01' d, 22 kwh 
from dual union all  
select 2 site, date '2023-04-11' d, 17 kwh 
from dual) 
,t2 as (
select t.* 
,last_value(kwh) over (partition by site order by d range between UNBOUNDED PRECEDING and interval '1' month preceding) prev_kwh 
from t 
)
select t2.*, round(kwh/prev_kwh*100, 2) pct
from t2
order by 1, 2
```

There was just a little thing to be added in order to get the percentage.

Answer (score 0):

With this sample data:

```sql
WITH 
    tbl (SITE, S_DATE, KWH) as 
        (
            Select 1, To_Date('2023-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 20 From Dual Union All
            Select 1, To_Date('2023-01-31', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 21 From Dual Union All
            Select 1, To_Date('2023-02-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 23 From Dual Union All
            Select 1, To_Date('2023-02-02', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 24 From Dual Union All
            Select 1, To_Date('2023-02-03', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 25 From Dual Union All
            Select 1, To_Date('2023-02-04', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 26 From Dual Union All
            Select 1, To_Date('2023-03-03', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 27 From Dual Union All
            Select 2, To_Date('2023-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 12 From Dual Union All
            Select 2, To_Date('2023-01-17', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 15 From Dual Union All
            Select 2, To_Date('2023-04-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 16 From Dual Union All
            Select 2, To_Date('2023-04-11', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 17 From Dual
        ),
```

... you could create a cte (grid) that collects the values from two rows into one row so you could have KWH in the same row with PREV_KWH and the KWH_DIFF... Used LEAD() analytic function with descending dates here ...

```sql
    grid as
        (
            Select  t.*, 
                    Nvl(LEAD(t.KWH) OVER(Partition By t.SITE Order By t.S_DATE DESC), KWH) "KWH_PREV", 
                    t.KWH - Nvl(LEAD(t.KWH) OVER(Partition By SITE Order By S_DATE DESC), 0) "KWH_DIFF",
                    t.S_DATE - Nvl(LEAD(t.S_DATE) OVER(Partition By SITE Order By S_DATE DESC), t.S_DATE) "DAY_DIFF",
                    Min(t.S_DATE) OVER(Partition By SITE, To_Char(t.S_DATE, 'yyyymm')) "MIN_MONTH_DATE"
            From tbl t
            Order By t.SITE, t.S_DATE DESC
        )
--
--  g r i d    R e s u l t:
      SITE S_DATE           KWH   KWH_PREV   KWH_DIFF   DAY_DIFF MIN_MONTH_DATE
---------- --------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- --------------
         1 03-MAR-23         27         26          1         27 03-MAR-23      
         1 04-FEB-23         26         25          1          1 01-FEB-23      
         1 03-FEB-23         25         24          1          1 01-FEB-23      
         1 02-FEB-23         24         23          1          1 01-FEB-23      
         1 01-FEB-23         23         21          2          1 01-FEB-23      
         1 31-JAN-23         21         20          1         30 01-JAN-23      
         1 01-JAN-23         20         20         20          0 01-JAN-23      
         2 11-APR-23         17         16          1         10 01-APR-23      
         2 01-APR-23         16         15          1         74 01-APR-23      
         2 17-JAN-23         15         12          3         16 01-JAN-23      
         2 01-JAN-23         12         12         12          0 01-JAN-23
```

... with grid's resulting dataset you can calculate whatever you want. Below is percentage calculation for monthly KWH_DIFF against current and previous KWH, taking in comparison first KWH reading in every month. You can do it in another way if this doesn't suit you

```sql
--   M a i n    S Q L        
Select  SITE, S_DATE, To_Char(S_DATE, 'Mon, yyyy') "MONTH", KWH, 
        Nvl(LEAD(KWH) OVER(Partition By SITE Order By S_DATE DESC), KWH) "KWH_PREV", 
        KWH - Nvl(LEAD(KWH) OVER(Partition By SITE Order By S_DATE DESC), KWH) "KWH_DIFF",
        Round((KWH - Nvl(LEAD(KWH) OVER(Partition By SITE Order By S_DATE DESC), KWH)) * 100 / KWH, 2) "DIFF_PERCENT_1",
        Round((KWH - Nvl(LEAD(KWH) OVER(Partition By SITE Order By S_DATE DESC), KWH)) * 100 / (Nvl(LEAD(KWH) OVER(Partition By SITE Order By S_DATE DESC), KWH)), 2) "DIFF_PERCENT_2"
From    grid g
Where   s_DATE = MIN_MONTH_DATE
--  
--  R e s u l t :
      SITE S_DATE    MONTH            KWH   KWH_PREV   KWH_DIFF DIFF_PERCENT_1 DIFF_PERCENT_2
---------- --------- --------- ---------- ---------- ---------- -------------- --------------
         1 03-MAR-23 Mar, 2023         27         23          4          14.81          17.39 
         1 01-FEB-23 Feb, 2023         23         20          3          13.04             15 
         1 01-JAN-23 Jan, 2023         20         20          0              0              0 
         2 01-APR-23 Apr, 2023         16         12          4             25          33.33 
         2 01-JAN-23 Jan, 2023         12         12          0              0              0
```

... if you want the result for one particular month just add the condition to the existing WHERE clause...

Comment: Hi d r, where is the :YEAR variable containing the year ? Also what is the difference between DIFF_PERCENT_1 and DIFFERENT_PERCENT2 ? Also I would like to use the real names of the columns of the table instead of columns from the dual table. Thank you!